# Get last week date range for a date based on Month

Tags: java

Right, so I've been pulling hairs trying to get this straight, hence would like some help here.

I'm trying to get the previous week start and end date based on the current date taking into consideration the month in which current date resides in.

For example,

```
CurrentDay = 01 April 2020(or any date btw 1 to 5)    Output: 30 March 2020 - 31 March 2020, note, since current day is 1st day of month and not start day of week.
CurrentDay = 06 April 2020(or any date btw 6 to 12)    Output: 01 April 2020 - 05 April 2020, note, since should consider days in current month only.
CurrentDay = 15 April 2020    Output: 06 April 2020 - 12 April 2020.
CurrentDay = 24 April 2020    Output: 13 April 2020 - 19 April 2020. 
CurrentDay = 30 April 2020    Output: 20 April 2020 - 26 April 2020. 
CurrentDay = 01 May 2020      Output: 27 April 2020 - 30 April 2020, note, since current day is 1st day of month.
CurrentDay = 01 June 2020(or any date btw 1 to 7)     Output: 25 May 2020 - 31 May 2020, note, since curent day is already start day of week.
```

This is what I've done so far,

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
c.setTime(sdf.parse("2020-04-01"));
System.out.println(c.getTime());

int i = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - c.getFirstDayOfWeek();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -i - 7);
Date start = c.getTime();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
Date end = c.getTime();
System.out.println(start + " - " + end);
```

But I'm pretty sure, I'm doing something wrong here as I'm unable to get expected results. Hence could someone help me out a bit?

PS:In my Locale week starts with Monday.

Comment: A tip: If you deal with multiple threads, `SimpleDateFormat` is not recommended

Comment: I think you should mention which java version do you use. There were quite a lot of changes between them

Comment: In case of java 6, take a look at https://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: Answers here use classes from the `java.time` package, such as `LocalDate` and `DayOfWeek`. You should use these classes, instead of the obsolete `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar` classes.

Comment: @MCEmperor: That is fine. But unfortunately none of the answers provided has helped to solve the full problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution is possible using WeekFields in French locale as Monday is start of the week:

```
private static void printPreviousWeekRange(LocalDate now) {
    TemporalField fieldISO = WeekFields.of(Locale.FRANCE).dayOfWeek();
    LocalDate prevWeekStart, prevWeekEnd;
    int dom = now.getDayOfMonth();
    DayOfWeek dow = now.getDayOfWeek();

    if (dom < 7 &&  dow != DayOfWeek.MONDAY) {
        prevWeekEnd = LocalDate.of(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), 1).minusDays(1);
        prevWeekStart = prevWeekEnd.with(fieldISO, 1);
    } else {
        prevWeekStart = now.minusDays(7).with(fieldISO, 1);
        if (prevWeekStart.getMonth().getValue() < now.getMonth().getValue() && dom != 1) {
            prevWeekStart = LocalDate.of(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), 1);
        }
        prevWeekEnd   = now.minusDays(7).with(fieldISO, 7);
    }
    System.out.println(now + ": start=" + prevWeekStart + ", end=" + prevWeekEnd);
}

private static void test() {
    printPreviousWeekRange(LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 1));
    printPreviousWeekRange(LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 2));
    printPreviousWeekRange(LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 4));
    printPreviousWeekRange(LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 5));
    printPreviousWeekRange(LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 6));
    printPreviousWeekRange(LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 7));
    printPreviousWeekRange(LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 12));
    printPreviousWeekRange(LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 15));
    printPreviousWeekRange(LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 24));
    printPreviousWeekRange(LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 30));
    printPreviousWeekRange(LocalDate.of(2020, 5, 1));
    printPreviousWeekRange(LocalDate.of(2020, 6, 1));}
```

output:

```
2020-04-01: start=2020-03-30, end=2020-03-31
2020-04-02: start=2020-03-30, end=2020-03-31
2020-04-04: start=2020-03-30, end=2020-03-31
2020-04-05: start=2020-03-30, end=2020-03-31
2020-04-06: start=2020-04-01, end=2020-04-05
2020-04-07: start=2020-04-01, end=2020-04-05
2020-04-12: start=2020-04-01, end=2020-04-05
2020-04-15: start=2020-04-06, end=2020-04-12
2020-04-24: start=2020-04-13, end=2020-04-19
2020-04-30: start=2020-04-20, end=2020-04-26
2020-05-01: start=2020-04-27, end=2020-04-30
2020-06-01: start=2020-05-25, end=2020-05-31
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I could see that if give now() as 2020-04-07, its giving wrong answer. It should be start=2020-04-01, end=2020-04-05 only. Could you help me with this?

Comment: So for the range since Apr 06 till Apr 12 previous week has to be Apr 01 - Apr 05, right?

Comment: Yes correct. Could you let me know as to how to handle it?

Comment: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two cents.

My approach would be to make a class which represents such a week-of-the-month – either a full week or a slice of it if a part of the week falls into another month.

It happens within the `of` method: the start and end date are the Monday before (or at) and the Sunday after (or at) the given `date` argument, but they are adjusted so the start and end dates never fall in another month. With `previous()` and `next()`, one can find adjacent week-of-months.

```
public class WeekOfMonth {

    private final LocalDate start;
    private final LocalDate end;

    private WeekOfMonth(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public static WeekOfMonth of(LocalDate date) {
        LocalDate startOfWeek = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
        LocalDate start = (startOfWeek.getMonthValue() == date.getMonthValue() ? startOfWeek : date.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayInMonth()));
        LocalDate endOfWeek = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
        LocalDate end = (endOfWeek.getMonthValue() == date.getMonthValue() ? endOfWeek : date.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayInMonth()));
        return new WeekOfMonth(start, end);
    }

    public WeekOfMonth previous() {
        return of(this.start.minusDays(1));
    }

    public WeekOfMonth next() {
        return of(this.end.plusDays(1));
    }
}
```

To find the previous week-of-month, simply call

```
WeekOfMonth.of(yourDate).previous()
```